# Subspace decomposition of the rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear operator on a $k$-vector space $V$. Is there a nice intuitive description of what the subspaces corresponding to the blocks of the rational canonical form of $T$ are?

The proof of the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID is pretty involved, so while it gives a clean proof of the existence of this form, it also hides the description of these spaces.